# Logstash AWS Kinesis JSON Input and output to AWS S3

Tags: json, logging, amazon-s3, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using AWS Kinesis for source input (has JSON for each triggered event, which writes to Kinesis Stream) in Logstash using 
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kinesis

I am using ES plugin for output and the data perfectly goes into Elasticsearch and I can query the data easily.

But, if I choose AWS S3 output plugin for Logstash, the data is sent to the S3 bucket I choose, but the JSON objects for each event are not segregated properly and I can't run a query on S3 data as the JSON is neither nested nor separated by proper Delimeter. This just does not happen when the input for S3 plugin is a JSON, for simple server logs, S3 separates every log event into separate lines using a "\n" delimeter.

Can someone help me here?

Logstash Config:
**INPUT**

```
input {
    kinesis {

       dynamodb app name
       application_name => "logstash"
       kinesis_stream_name => "data_stream"
       type => "kinesis"
       region => "us-west-2"
       metrics => "cloudwatch"
     }
    }
```

**FILTER** #NOT SHOWING IT HERE,

**OUTPUT**

```
s3{
           access_key_id => "XXXX"
           secret_access_key => "XXX"
           region => "us-west-2"
           bucket => "rtest"
           time_file => 1
           prefix => "Logs/"
           canned_acl => "private"
           codec => json

    }
```

Can I somehow use a delimeter option like delimiter => "\n"
to segregate different JSON entries based a delimeter.

Example of JSON lines that get stored in the s3 file in the bucket is as follows:

```
{{timestamp:dasdsa,xyz:abc},{hello:bye}}{{timestamp:dasdsd,xzy:bcn},{hello:hi}}
```

So, there is no separator between two JSONs which I can use. If you need more details please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
code => "json"
```

for your last line of your output code? You need the quotations.

Comment: No that did not work either. 

We ended up using open source version of https://snowplowanalytics.com/
Then we used AWS Lambda function to throw data to S3

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.